# VBScript IsDate Function # character not working in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

What is the difference when "#" character is used in ISData funcion.

IsDate(#01/31/10#)- returns False in VBscript.

where as in VB.NET  it throws exception.

Any inputs on how to resemble the VBScript behavior in VB.NET

Comment: VBScript is **not** VB.NET - they are completely different languages with some superficial syntax similarities.

Comment: What is the exception? What culture is the application running under?

Answer (score 2):

The following works perfectly fine in VB.NET and returns True:

```
Dim b = IsDate(#1/31/2010#)
```

The syntax of [Date Literals in VB.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3eaydw6e.aspx) is specified as follows:

> You must enclose a Date literal within number signs (# #). You must specify the date value in the format M/d/yyyy, for example #5/31/1993#. This requirement is independent of your locale and your computer's date and time format settings.